# Shellcode not working ( from protostar )

Tags: gdb, reverse-engineering, shellcode

Hello guys i want to create a similar file like Stack5 in protostar
The only problem is that when i execute a shellcode , or just \xCC it only works in gdb.

The source code

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  char container[32];
  gets(container);
}
```

the command used to build the executable

```
gcc -z execstack -fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -m32  -g binary1.c -o binary1
```

for example a \x90 interrupt

```
import struct
pad="AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGGHHHHIIII"
eip=struct.pack("I",0xffffd6a0+4) 
payload="\x90"*12+"\xCC"*4+"\x90"*12
print pad+eip+payload
```

all the results i get are only segmentation fault ( dump)

Picture here for demonstration [Image for comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSaOC.png)

Comment: working on ubuntu x64 if it helps

Comment: Your source code would never compile. You'll get better answers if you show *actual* code. Also, where did you get the value `0xffffd6a0` from?

Comment: @EmployedRussian Hello, ty for your answer. I got the address from: I put a breakpoint on ret, then si, then get the address of $esp register.
Secondly, why do you say the code will never compile? (I will upload the executable shortly
)

Comment: It will not compile because the code has not any function (e.g. int main() {...}). Also, as @EmployedRussian said, where did you get the value 0xffffd6a0 from? Because GDB could use these address for usability. Normally with ASLR you will not know these address. You should find a ROP gadget to execute your payload.

Comment: Sorry I copied badly the main. Edited.

Comment: @sinkmanu ty for the 2 suggestions

Comment: @sinkmanu: in this wargame, [there is no ASLR nor NX](https://exploit-exercises.com/protostar/) (but it may be enabled in OP's virtual machine). This address found by OP may be wrong because of the offset induced by the system when running the binary inside or outside the debugger, environment variables and argument being placed _before_ the stack (in higher addresses) in process' memory. I would recommend to use a bigger nopsled, no need of ROP chain in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Buffer overflow works in gdb but not without it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775186/buffer-overflow-works-in-gdb-but-not-without-it)

Comment: @swapgs ty for the information and the link for  the duplicate, really usefull