# linux syscall uname for x86

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls

I only study assembler (nasm) and have more question. For example i want make asm code that get info about operating system. I use linux 86 bit. In a code i use syscall uname. In a browser have more information about this syscall and code. I found this link:

https://github.com/hc0d3r/asm/blob/master/uname.asm

[Uname syscall in buffer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638845/uname-syscall-in-buffer-overflow)

But i use 86 bit system. So, i tried rewrite code for my system. I understand, that in register eax i should move value of syscall (0x7a or 122) and in register ebx addres of array.

I used first link as example, but get error. So, can you help me decide this problem?

This is my main code:

```
extern printf

SYS_WRITE equ 4
SYS_UNAME equ 122
SYS_EXIT equ 60
STDOUT equ 1

section .data
str: db '%s',10,0
UTSNAME_SIZE equ 65
space db ' '
break_line db 0xa

section .bss
uname_res resb UTSNAME_SIZE*5

section .text
global main
main:
    mov eax, 0x7A
    mov ebx, uname_res
    int 80h


push dword [uname_res]
    push dword str
    call printf

mov eax, 1
int 80h
```

and I got this error:

```
segmentation error (memory dump made)
```

This mistake on printf. Sorry for my crooked english

Comment: I'm not used to pushing arguments to the stack, but have you tried `push str` instead of `push dword [str]`? Also, by 86 bit do you mean `x86`?

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 I change push. Now "push dword str". In the internet used "push dword str". I use linux x86

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 The error remains. Does not display information

Comment: I see. I'm not using to using `printf` in NASM, so I don't want to give any further advice which could be incorrect and could potentially cause more issues.

Comment: **x86 doesn't mean 86-bit**. There are only 16, 32 and 64-bit x86

Comment: @phuclv I had mistakes ;) Thank you for correction :)

Comment: Didn't recall what syscall 0x7a does, but `push dword [uname_res]` is probably wrong, you probably want `push uname_res`. Also, familiarize yourself with gdb, radare2, or any debugger, they will help you shed some light on the crashes.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thank you. Say me please, how you understand where problem. This is exp or you have useful book?

Comment: Make sure to understand everything you wrote in the source code. Why it's done this way and not this other one. For example, what the square brackets do and what a pointer is. Then familiarize yourself with a debugger, it will show you the memory addresses and values involved, making some mistakes obvious.

Comment: @Oleg: in this case, the fact that `printf "%s"` takes a pointer arg means that pushing 4 bytes of ASCII characters is certainly going to be wrong.  And yes, `uname()` fills a struct of `char[]` arrays, so the buffer contents are ASCII bytes, not pointers.  As Margaret said, using a debugger will make it clear what value is in memory at `dword [uname_res]`, so you can just check whether it's a valid pointer or not.

Comment: I wrote code for linux x86. Look it here (maybe will be useful)

https://github.com/OlegInfoSecurity/cpu_name

https://github.com/OlegInfoSecurity/cpuid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote code for linux x86. Look it here (maybe will be useful)

https://github.com/OlegInfoSecurity/uname_x86

This error occurred when i output (print) info. I changed code for output info and program is work.

Comment: It's better to have answers here on the site, instead of linked.  Can you write an explanation of what the problem was, with an example of working code?